# Microsoft Report: RDLC needs to be adjusted from the code. How?

Tags: report, rdlc

Is there some way to change the label text or expression for the field in a run time?

I have a report that needs to be adjusted depending on the condition. I can set up names for the controls on .rdlc file but I have no idea how to access them from the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

rdlc files are simple xml files you can load them into XmlDocument and work whit them like whit any outer xml file. If you give more information like simple xml and what you want do i can give you saome kind of exmaple.
Here si the xsd scheme which is used to validate the xml.This specify the xml format used in rdlc files
[SQL Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154044%28SQL.90%29.aspx)
[SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154044%28SQL.100%29.aspx)
Best Regards,
Iordan